# cast from 'char*' to 'int' loses precision

Tags: c++

am having a problem converting a char* into am int in a 64 bit machine .
i know the problem is on 64 bit sizeof(char*) is 8 and sizeof(int) is 4.
here's the code :

```
void books::update()
{
    int b_id[100],qty[100],i=0,max;
    stmt.str("");
    stmt<<" Select book_id,qty from purchase where recieves ='T' and inv IS NULL;";
    query=stmt.str();
    q =query.c_str();
    mysql_query(conn,q);
    res_set=mysql_store_result(conn);
    stmt.str("");
    stmt<<" Update purchases set inv=1 where recieves ='T' and inv is NULL";
    query=stmt.str();
    q=query.c_str();
    mysql_query(conn,q);
    while((row=mysql_fetch_row(res_set))!=NULL)
    {
        b_id[i]=(int)row[0];
        qty[i]= (int)row[1];
        i++;
    }
    max=i;
    for(i =0;i<max;i++)
    {
        stmt.str("");
        stmt<<" update books set qty ="<< qty[i]<<"where id = "<<b_id[i]<<";";
        query= stmt.str();
        q= query.c_str();
        mysql_query(conn,q);


    }
    cout<<" The order recieved has been updated .";



}
```

the bug is in these two lines :

```
b_id[i]=(int)row[0];
qty[i]= (int)row[1];
```

i tried to use (long) instead of (int) ,expecting it to convert my int from 4 bytes to 8 bytes and i still got the same error (cast from 'char*' to 'int' loses precision )

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by converting a `char *` to an `int` in the first place?

Comment: Have you ever wondered why you need so many variables? `query = stmt.str(); q = query.c_str(); mysql_query(conn, q);` could be replaced with `mysql_query(conn, stmt.str().c_str());` and two variables and two lines of code have been eliminated. You  don't have to use a variable when you call a function, you can use an *expression* too.

Comment: What is the type of `row` ? (I don't see its declaration.)

Comment: For pointers use `uintptr_t`. That can hold a pointer on the given platform. However, what you are doing there is almost certainly wrong; there is almost _never_ a good reason to convert a pointer to an integer. One possible reason are fast string literal caches mapped by pointers instead of by strings themselves, but that’s definitely not the use case here.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library has two fixed width `typedef`s capable of holding a pointer to `void` which are defined in `<cstdint>`:

```
std::intptr_t   // signed
std::uintptr_t  // unsigned
```

However, you do not convert a C string to an integer via a cast. The C string must be interpreted somehow. Example:

```cpp
#include <sstream>

// ...

// put the two C strings in an istringstream:
std::istringstream is(std::string(row[0]) + ' ' + std::string(row[1]));

// and extract the values
if(is >> b_id[i] >> qty[i]) {
    // success
}
```

Other options are to use [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) or
[`std::strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol). Example:

```cpp
b_id[i] = std::stoi(row[0]); // may throw std::invalid_argument ...
qty[i] = std::stoi(row[1]);  // ... or std::out_of_range
```

Comment: yes the std::stoi worked ,thanks for helping .

Answer (score 1):

Change `int` to `std::intptr_t` everywhere, including the array declarations. You need `#include <cstdint>` for that.

More info about integer types in C++: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: I don't think cast from `char*` to `int` (or `intptr_t`) is what OP really wants here.